# POST var not being passed in PHP whatsoever

Tags: apache, post, php

The PHP file:

```
    <?

print_r($_REQUEST);
$thispage = 'login';
require('db.php');
if($_POST['admin_username'] && $_POST['admin_password']) {
    $query="SELECT * FROM login where name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['admin_username'])."' AND pass = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['admin_password'])."' AND level='admin'";
    echo $query;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if($row['name'] && $row['pass']) {
        $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        setcookie('isAdmin' , 1, time()+3600, '/', $settings['cookiedomain']);
        setcookie('loggedin' , 1, time()+3600, '/', $settings['cookiedomain']);
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();}
    else {
        header("Location: login.php?msg=Invalid%20Login");
        exit();
    }
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Admin Area</title>
<link href="style.css" rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bubble-tooltip.css" media="screen">
<style>
.style1 {color: #171717}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='content' style='width: 500px; border: 1px solid #171717; margin-top: 100px; background-color: #404040;'>
<h1 align="center"><img src="header.jpg" width="333" height="91" /></h1>
<p align="center">Welcome to the Admin Area</p>
<? if($_GET['msg']) { ?>
<center>
<p style='color: #FF9900; font-weight: bold;'><? echo $_GET['msg']; ?></p>
</center>
<? } ?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <table width="311" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="68"><strong>Username</strong></td>
      <td width="231"><input type="text" name="admin_username" style='background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #1F1F1F; font-size: 11px; color: #1F1F1F; width: 200px;' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Password</strong></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="admin_password" style='background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #1F1F1F; font-size: 11px; color: #1F1F1F; width: 200px;'  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Login" />
      </div></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id='footer'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

At the top I have `print_r($_REQUEST);` and all I get back is Array(). Same result when I use `print_r($_POST);`.

Firebug shows the POST vars being submitted for sure, without a doubt, and the keynames match up perfectly.

here's copy-pasted data from Firebug, under the POST section:

```
Partsmultipart/form-data
admin_username  jeff
admin_password  51622384
button  Login
```

post_max_size set to 8M as per `phpinfo();` command.

What am I possibly missing? This was working on our previous server. After migration, nobody can log in thanks to this issue.

Comment: Since you're posting the form to itself you should be able to show all your code.

Comment: Any errors in your server log?

Comment: You can use `action=""` instead. Make sure you're posting to the right page.

Comment: No error log, and action="" was the original script. I made it more explicit in order to be more specific. Removed it again, same result. Array() returned, rather than the full $_POST or $_REQUEST array.

Comment: Added the Firebug snippet as well to the question above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it was a redirect loop issue!

Firebug was a bit misleading, but upon inspecting, i realized that there were two lines in a row:

POST login.php
GET index.php

Indicating it attempted to loop to index.php after a successful run. Why it didn't ignore the header() command after the print_r() command should have spat out a result, I am not sure. Generally headers can only be passed BEFORE there is output.

Anyway, index.php had a var being checked, and upon false it would send back to login.php:

```
$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS['isAdmin']
```

This was written by the previous developer, and this doesn't work on the newer version of PHP.

Hence I changed that up to

```
$_COOKIE['isAdmin']
```

Hope this helps.

PHP version changes can be a pain in the ass, especially if the code you inherit isn't up to par.

Answer (score 1):

Form's action should be `action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` if you are posting to the same page.

Comment: Okay, so I think the problem is your php is not able to recognize superglobal variables. Open php.ini and set variables order as GPCS. `variables_order = "GPCS"`

Comment: May be in your php.ini, there will be no Get Post (GP) variables set. Also, don't forget to restart the server after making any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your form looks ok , but I have a couple of suggestions:

1. I don't see why you need to have the enctype="multipart/form-data". That is used when you want your form to upload files.
2. Since you are using method=POST, why not look in the $_POST array instead of the $_REQUEST array?
3. You might want to consider applying HTMLENTITIES to  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to avoid possible exploits. (action= )
4. Does your new server recognize the 
   `<?` shorthand (as opposed to using `<?php ?>` )?

Ok, so having said all that, I'm not seeing anything wrong with your form, but I do recommend you consider some of the changes I suggest.

Comment: #1 - removing the enctype did not make a difference.
#2 - tried both print_r($_POST) AND print_r($_REQUEST) to make sure. nothign.
#3 - I'll look into that, but right now i'm more concerned about why my new server rejects my POST vars. 
#4 - Absolutely. The print_r($_POST) does return Array() so the php commands work well. It's just returning a complete blank.

Comment: I thought of this on the way home. You are not seeing the $_REQUEST array because your are executing a HEADER('location command. So, the page reloads and you see nothing. When your authentication fails, why not just let the page continue to load, and display the error message?

Comment: That would be genius, except the previous coder had it set that way, and I'm trying to minimize my efforts in getting this live and getting the job done... really don't want to deal with this guy's messy coding. This stuff is awful what I'm dealing with! I miss my own code.

Answer (score 0):

i have test your code its working fine;-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['button']) && !empty($_POST['button']))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    die;

}
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <table width="311" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="68"><strong>Username</strong></td>
      <td width="231"><input type="text" name="admin_username" style='background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #1F1F1F; font-size: 11px; color: #1F1F1F; width: 200px;' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Password</strong></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="admin_password" style='background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #1F1F1F; font-size: 11px; color: #1F1F1F; width: 200px;'  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Login" />
      </div></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

output:-

```
Array
(
    [admin_username] => admin
    [admin_password] => Pass@word1
    [button] => Login
)
```