# $_POST is empty in php5.6

Tags: php, html, apache, wampserver, php-5.6

I've tried almost all solutions related to empty $_POST after submitting form in stack overflow but none of them solved my problem.I'am using wamp server and using phpstorm.

- changed the values of post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in php.ini
- $_GET works fine
- tried using other ide and editors
- isset returns false
- var_dump shows that the array is empty
- changed method="post" to method="POST"
  My code:
  main.html

  ```
  <html>
  <body> 
  <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
  </body><br>
  </html>
  ```

  welcome.php

  ```
  <html>
  <body>
  Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
  Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
  </body>
  </html>`
  ```

error -

Welcome

> Notice: Undefined index: name in
>   
> C:\Users\user\PhpstormProjects\tryphp\welcome.php on line 4

Your email address is:

> Notice: Undefined index: email in
>   
> C:\Users\user\PhpstormProjects\tryphp\welcome.php on line 5

Comment: check browser network tab to see if post parameters are sent to server

Comment: It's working perfectly. Make sure you have both files(main.html and welcome.php) in the same folder.

Comment: Do you have `P` letter in `variables_order` directive in php.ini ? Did you try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));` ?

Comment: Is not a path problem because the welcome.php action is loaded

Comment: variables_order = "GPCS"   Output of `var_dump($_REQUEST);`  is array(0) { } and output of `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));` is string(16) "name=df&email=df". "df" was my input for both name and email.

Comment: It is working for me. Both files obviously are in the same folder. That's why the Undefined index error is shown. Else it will be file not found.Basically the post variable is not being passed at all

Comment: both main.html and welcome.php are in the same folder

Comment: You're saying you are using wamp server, yet the error report you gave us says the location of your files is `C:\Users\user\PhpstormProjects\tryphp\welcome.php`. Why are your .php files not in your WAMP's root directory, and are you accessing your files through localhost?

Comment: @ FrankSunnyman phpsorm is connected to wamp server and yes I'm accessing my files through localhost - "http://localhost:63342/tryphp/welcome.php"

Comment: @user6275035 Is your PHP configured right? If you add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` somewhere in your welcome.php or in a new php file and you navigate to it, does it show any errors/oddities? Is the post_max_size set correctly?

Comment: @FrankSunnyman  No error in <?php phpinfo(); ?>  and post_max_size = 60M

Comment: *"phpsorm is connected to wamp server"* – I'm pretty sure the problem lies here somewhere. Does the same happen with a standard standalone WAMP server? How exactly is it "connected"?

Comment: what if you change main.html to main.php?

Comment: @user3253002 no change

Comment: Do you open it in IDE or in real browser (Chrome, FF, etc..) ?

Comment: @Jessie Jackson Chrome

Answer (score 0):

From a quick test, your code works as it should on my server.

Running through the PHP config file (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini) I found these items that might be worth investigating

```
; Whether PHP will read the POST data.
; This option is enabled by default.
; Most likely, you won't want to disable this option globally. It causes $_POST
; and $_FILES to always be empty; the only way you will be able to read the
; POST data will be through the php://input stream wrapper. This can be useful
; to proxy requests or to process the POST data in a memory efficient fashion.
; http://php.net/enable-post-data-reading
;enable_post_data_reading = Off
```

So go into your php.ini and search enable_post_data_reading, if you don't find it, put it in manually (normally at the end of the file) and make sure it's On

```
enable_post_data_reading = On
```

**My Version Information:**

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 (cli) (built: May 19 2016 19:05:57)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

If you still get nothing, then have a look at your access log. It should show the POST request coming into your server;

```
255.255.255.255 - - [13/Sep/2016:10:16:00 -0400] "POST /stackoverflow/welcome.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1226 "http://255.255.255.255/stackoverflow/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/255.255.255.255 Safari/537.36"
```

(Ignore the IP address info, I edited it to protect my server :))

If it's not showing a POST request, then thats one place to start.

Also you can press F12 on your browser (Or ctrl+shift+i) to open the debug console, click on network (at the top)  Be on your form, click the submit button, and you will see a network request go out.  Click on it, click on "headers", scroll to the bottom, and look at the info your browser is actually sending to the server.

Hopefully something in this lot helps you.  Let us know please :)

Comment: I can see the correct form data in headers section but $_POST is still empty in welcome.php

Comment: There are no POSTs in access log, only GETs. Is it possible that all POST requests are getting converted to GET?

Comment: Yes that is possible, but not something that I have a lot of experience with, just a quick google and this turned up (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728231/post-request-getting-converted-to-get-when-url-rewriting-is-done-in-apache-httpd)  Are you using Proxy/URL Rewrite or anything else between yourself and welcome.php that might be tampering with your connection?  Maybe even just changing the action on your form to the full URI of welcome.php so that mod-rewrite does not change it to www.site from site.

Comment: This is also interesting, though perhaps not applicable in this case.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872649/post-var-not-being-passed-in-php-whatsoever  Either way, this is likely not a PHP issue, most likely an Apache issue.  if you have SSH access to your machine, you can check compiled in modules with "apache2ctl -l"

Comment: not using any proxy and I've seen both the links. I'll try reinstalling wamp.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to work if you give any input in those fields. Check this, Name the submit button and onsubmit that button the form will go to Welcome.php

**`Main.html`**

```
<html>
<body> 
    <form action="welcome.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submitForm">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**`welcome.php`**

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php 
    $name = "";
    $email = "";
    if (isset($_POST["submitForm"])) {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["name"];
    }
    ?>
    Welcome <?php echo $name; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $email; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And then your error will be gone if the fields are empty too.

If this not working that means, your `welcome.php` is not in the same folder of `main.html`. Check that..

Answer (score -1):

In welcome.php add as first line:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to check if your post is empty...

Comment: This is rather a comment and doesn't offer any solution to OPs question!

Comment: Well, the solution it is an ultimate leaf in our tree. But for achieve that we need to know some details. In this situation, if the post is empty, the problem is not from welcome file and should check in main.html or in server configuration...

Comment: output of `var_dump($_REQUEST);` is array(0) { }

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']);

Comment: 2. check post_max_size value on php.ini. If 0, you can not send post data

Comment: 3. Check variables_order in php.ini. You should have a P in string like: "EGPCS"

Comment: Output of `var_dump($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']);` Undefined index: CONTENT_TYPE in C:\Users\user\PhpstormProjects\tryphp\welcome.php on line 6
NULL

Comment: post_max_size  is 8M and variables_order = "GPCS"

Comment: if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'])) { $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; } var_dump($_POST);

Comment: output of  `if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'])) { $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; } var_dump($_POST); ` is array(0) { }

Comment: Can you check the apache and php error logs, please, for your last request and see if it is an error reported!

Comment: apache logs have no errors but php log has errors related to undefined variables - name and email.

Comment: one more question: do you enable mod_rewrite for your apache config ? In wamp shouls be easy ...

Comment: The statement LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is uncommented in httpd.conf if that is what you mean by apache config.

Comment: Under Wamp menu should be something like apache module > rewrite_module or something like that ...

Comment: if nothing help, try to reinstall your wamp as ultimate solution

Comment: Welcome! Please check if other extension (like PHP Storm ...)  is not interfering with your wamp (php settings)...