# $_POST variable is empty after fetch request

Tags: php

In react i write

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://ozencalc.ru", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        action: "operations-update"
      })
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((res) => alert(res));
  }, []);
```

so i'm sending an object as a body and expect to read it on php server
where i write

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

but i get an empty array instead of object with key "action"

What can be the cause that php server variable $_POST doesn't content value

```
[
  "action" => "operations-update"
]
```

can it be some hosting server problem or i misunderstood how php works?

Comment: Is this really what your PHP code looks like? Because Postman request also returns `null`. so most likely not JS related

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471257/post-is-empty-in-php5-6

Comment: Content-Type = `application/json` wont be in `$_POST`, `$_POST` gets filled when its `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` [is in the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) you should use [file_get_contents('php://input')](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your $_POST will be empty because data was sent in body, try:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: That ineed worked for me @Gabski. Question remains why not php reads an interprets the body? Certainly when `Content-Type` is set?